# installing node.js cPanel X

Tags: node.js, cpanel

I have been tasked with installing [node.js](http://nodejs.org/) on a linux server, the login information I have been given brings me to cpanel and I'm not sure at this time if I can ssh into the machine. So I'm not sure how to go about installing it as there doesn't seem to be any access to a command prompt. If someone could point me in the right direction I would appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least in the [domain owner demo](http://www.cpanel.net/products/cpanelwhm/try-demo.html), there's a menu point Security->SSH/Shell access. Are you sure you don't have that?
If not, you can still compile node on your machine if it has the same architecture as the server and upload it in its path, but you won't be able to compile node addons later. It's an ugly approach, don't do it.

Comment: indeed I see it in your link but it's not on the page when I log in